# What is the usage of third argument objtype in Python descriptor's __get__

Tags: python, descriptor

I know that in Python we have to supply `__get__` function when implementing a descriptor. The interface is like:

```
def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
    pass
```

My question is:

Why we have to supply `objtype` arg? What is `objtype` used for?

I did not see some examples about the usage of this arg.

Comment: [The documentation of  `object.__get__`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__get__#object.__get__) does not mention `objtype`. Where did you read about it?

Comment: @LutzHorn `owner` is `objtype` in this case, i.e the class.

Comment: http://intermediatepythonista.com/classes-and-objects-ii-descriptors

Comment: Part of your confusion is that you have the function prototype wrong.  According to the docs linked by Lutz Horn, `owner` (not `objtype`, as already pointed out) does _not_ default to `None` in any version of Python.

Answer (score 3):

It gives users an option to do something with the class that was used to call the descriptor.

In normal cases when the descriptor is called through the instance we can get the object type by calling `type(ins)`.

But when it is called through the class `ins` will be `None`and we won't be able to access the class object if the third argument was not present.

---

Take functions in Python for example, each function is an instance of `types.FunctionType` and has a [`__get__` method](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b48e1b48e670/Objects/funcobject.c#l630) that can be used to make that function a bound or unbound method.

```
>>> from types import FunctionType
>>> class A(object):
    pass
...
>>> def func(self):
    print self
...
>>> ins = A()
>>> types.FunctionType.__get__(func, ins, A)() # instance passed
<__main__.A object at 0x10f07a150>
>>> types.FunctionType.__get__(func, None, A)  # instance not passed
<unbound method A.func>
>>> types.FunctionType.__get__(func, None, A)()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-211-d02d994cdf6b>", line 1, in <module>
    types.FunctionType.__get__(func, None, A)()
TypeError: unbound method func() must be called with A instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
>>> types.FunctionType.__get__(func, None, A)(A())
<__main__.A object at 0x10df1f6d0>
```

Comment: If it is useful for `__get__`, why is the `owner` parameter absent from `__set__` and `__delete__` as well?

Comment: @Maggyero Any usecases you could think of having `owner` or `objtype` in `__set__`  and `__delete__`, when they are called from class not instance?

Comment: An application I can think of is managing access to *class* attributes (similar to [managing access to *instance* attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#managed-attributes)), where `A.x` would look up `A._x` (already possible thanks to the `owner` parameter), `A.x = 'foo'` would update `A._x` (not currently possible) and `del A.x` would delete `A._x` (not currently possible).

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [`object.__get__(self, instance, owner)`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__get__#object.__get__):

> `owner` is always the owner class, while `instance` is the instance that the attribute was accessed through, or `None` when the attribute is accessed through the `owner`.

So you don't *supply* `owner`, it is set depending on how `__get__` is called.

Comment: Do you know some circumstance where *owner* is used? I just don't know the purpose of this arg.